# create objects within code and add to arraylist, BlueJ

Tags: java, swing, bluej

I am wanting to have objects already created in the code so I don't have to construct each object but I don't know how to add them to an array List, this is what I have so far:

```
public class MenuItem
{    
    private String foodName;
    private String foodType;
    private float price;
    private int calories;    


    public MenuItem(String nameFood, String typeFood, float foodPrice, int caloryCount)

    {     
    foodName = nameFood;
    foodType = typeFood;
    price = foodPrice;
    calories = caloryCount;

   }
```

I had this set up but I am going to change it so I have a class with all the different menu sorts already added in so then all I have to do is add them to an Array List but I am not sure how to do this, just showing you this so you can have an idea of what I was planning on adding to the Array List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how to create an ArrayList for your `MenuItem` class:

```
AraryList<MenuItem> list = new ArrayList<MenuList>();
```

To add MenuItem objects to your list:

```
list.add(new MenuItem(foodName, foodType, price, calories));
```

If you want to create sub-classing for your MenuItem:

```
class MenuItem
{
    //your class implementation
}

class SubMenuItem extends MenuItem
{
    //your class implementation    
}

ArrayList<MenuItem> list = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
list.add(new MenuItem(foodName, foodType, price, calories));
list.add(new SubMenuItem( /*your arguments*/ ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a static List like this?

```
public class Main {

    public static final List<MenuItem> items;

    static {
        items = new LinkedList<>();
        items.add(new MenuItem("Steak", "Meat", 13.50f, 378));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Bread", "Grain", 2.50f, 79));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Rice", "Grain", 4.50f, 206));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just used an array list rather then just a list because I will change it in the future to be able to add more items from the UI instead of coding them in